# TeXLive 2014 + Presentations doesn't compile

Tags: beamer, miktex, texlive, texstudio

G'day everyone,

I've just installed TeXLive 2014 (full install) and trying to run some test files using TeXStudio (Windows). All running smoothly so far (PDFLaTex), until I hit a problem with creating presentations.

Below is a minimal version (I based it off a template from latextemplates.com):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{Madrid} }
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{booktabs}

\title[Short title]{Full Title of the Talk}
\author{John Smith} \institute[UCLA] { University of California \\ 
\medskip \textit{john@smith.com} }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} \titlepage \end{frame}
\begin{frame} Hello world! \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \Huge{\centerline{The End}} \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I can't even compile anything and get this weird-looking error message:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "presentation_1_simple".tex
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table 
Syntax Warning: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Process exited with error(s)
```

The log file is mainly uneventful (I've uploaded it [here](http://pastebin.com/TcMrfnge) for posterity), but I've included the end section below:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file d:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/a
rt/beamericonbook.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The weird thing is that the PDF file referred to above does exist in the location specified (and opens fine).

I have also run this code using a portable MikTeX distribution (2.9), and it compiled/output without any issues at all, so I don't think it's a coding issue. (Unfortunately MikTeX has a lot of issues with foreign languages and fonts that TL 2014 handles much better, so it's not a viable option to switch).

What has got wrong? Any hints/thoughts on where to look or test to try and get it working?

Hope my information is clear. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `d:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/art/beamericonbook.pdf` exist on your system? Can you open it in a PDF viewer? The code compiles fine here with TL 2014. (Although you ought not use `\centerline` - at least, very rarely and not here.)

Comment: @cfr yes the file exists and can be opened fine. I'll update the original question to make it clearer.

Comment: No ideas. But don't worry. Somebody who knows something about Windows will take a look. (That's just not me.) Welcome to TeX SE, by the way!

Comment: Have you updated TL recently?

Comment: @Siminore no, just did a fresh full-install, so assumed everything would be up to date...

Comment: MWE works fine with recent pdflatex